# DB:select Laravel 5 how to pass query results to my posts

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables, users and posts, where users have their coordinates (user_latitude/user_longitude) and posts have their ones (address_latitude/address_longitude).

I manage to display an array of results with the function below but what I would like to do is to extract the temporary field "distance" and associate it to my posts so in my view I can display something like:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<p>Distance from you: {{$post->distance}}</p>
...
```

Some help on this would be more than appreciated.

```
public function distance(){
    $lat = Auth::user()->user_latitude;
    $lng = Auth::user()->user_longitude;
    $radius = 10;

    $data = DB::select('SELECT id, title, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( address_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( address_longitude ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( address_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM posts HAVING distance < '.$radius.';');

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions):

```
public function my_function()
{
    $lat = Auth::user()->user_latitude;
    $lng = Auth::user()->user_longitude;
    $radius = 10;

    $data = DB::table('posts')
        ->select('id', 'title', DB::raw('( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( address_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( address_longitude ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( address_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
        ->having('distance', '<', $radius)
        ->get();

    return view('posts.later', ['posts' => $data]);
}
```

Now if you want to use it in your views here is how you do it using [foreach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#control-structures):

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <p>Distance from you: {{$post->distance}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It seems to be working except // ->having('distance', '<', '.$radius.')

Comment: This is working: ->get()->where('id', 1); fetch object with id, title and distance where id = 1.

Comment: But this ->having('distance', '<', '.$radius.') or this ->get()->where('distance', '<', '.$radius.'); return an empty results: [ ]

Comment: @Alex Yes because you have to use `having` only if you have `groupBy`. Try changing `->having('distance', '<', '.$radius.')` to `->whereRaw('distance < ' . $radius.)`

Comment: @Alex By the way `->get()` should be at the end of query. You have to add `WhereRaw` or `Where` and THEN use `->get()`

Comment: Thanks. Now, the query ->whereRaw('distance < ' .$radius.) is bringing the following error "syntax error, unexpected ')'" and difficult to know what is going on

Comment: @Alex Oh that was a typo. Remove `.` after `$radius`. Correct is `->whereRaw('distance < ' .$radius)`

Comment: @Alex And also use `var_dump($data)` instead of `return $data` to make sure if query works. And then use `return $data` again.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the field 'distance' : "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Result as follow if I remove the query whereraw: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#267 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#270 (1) {
      ["distance"]=>
      float(3.821392999219)
    }
  ...
    [7]=>
    object(stdClass)#279 (1) {
      ["distance"]=>
      float(184.96001575228)
    }
  }
}
[{"distance":3.8213929992190283},...{"distance":33.115338642494535},{"distance":184.96001575228377}]

Comment: @Alex Sorry for late reply. You can use `having` in this case. By the way it returned empty when you used ‍‍`having` because `$radious` was in `''`. See my updated answer now.

Comment: Brilliant Sky. The other part of the question was how can I now display something like {{$post->distance}} in my view?

Comment: In my PostController I have the following function. Can I pass my $dataonto this by any chance?                   $posts = Post::all();
        $posts = Post::where('date_time','>=', $time_limit)
                    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                    ->get();

        return view('posts.later')-> with('posts', $posts);

Comment: @Alex Yes it's possible to pass variables to views. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hey Sky thanks a lot. I have an index function where I post all filtering by date ($posts). Can I bind the 2 functions together to pass $posts and $data in same view? So in view I can do: @foreach($posts as $post) {{$post->category}}, {{$post->title}}, ... and {{$data->distance}}

Comment: Here is my index function: public function index() 
{ 

$now = Carbon::now(); 
$time_limit = Carbon::now()->AddHours(2); 

$posts = Post::all(); 
$posts = Post::where('date_time','>=', $time_limit) 
->orderBy('created_at','desc') 
->get(); 

return view('posts.index')-> with('posts', $posts); 
}

Comment: Is it the case of adding the DB::select query to the above function and pass only $posts (including 'distance') in to my view? Your help is priceless.

Comment: @Alex You can pass unlimited number of variables to your views: `return view('posts.later', ['posts' => $data, 'another_variable', => $posts]);`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public function distance() {

    $lat = Auth::user()->user_latitude;
    $lng = Auth::user()->user_longitude;
    $radius = 10;

    $data = DB::select('SELECT id, title, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( address_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( address_longitude ) - radians('.$lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( address_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM posts HAVING distance < '.$radius.';');

    return $data->get();

}
```

Comment: "Call to a member function get() on array" is what I get when using the above

Comment: @Alex  In the case, you are passing a class to the variable, but you have not run any action for get the result.
look at this docs you know about this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions